# Can I claim a route longer than the number of trains I have left?

Tags: ticket-to-ride

On the last move, after only 2 train pieces remains, is it possible to claim a 3-carriage route, if you have the 3 required color cards but only 2 plastic trains left to place on the board?

Answer (score 20):

No, you cannot claim a route longer than the number of plastic trains you have left.

[Ticket to Ride Rules](https://ncdn0.daysofwonder.com/tickettoride/en/img/tt_rules_2015_en.pdf)

> Claim a Route
>   The player may claim a route on the board by playing a set of Train Car cards 
>   that match the color and length of the route and 
>   **then placing one of his colored trains on each space of this route**...
>
> Claiming Routes
>   ... When a route is claimed, the player **places one of his plastic trains in each of the spaces of the route**...

Comment: And explicitly from the publisher: "No you absolutely can't play more cards/lay more tracks than you have trains left!" --Eric Hautemont, DoW, 2004. https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/19644/train-car-pieces-end-game

Comment: It would ruin the resource management part of the game, since you could calm a 4 or 5 route with 2 trains.

Comment: @Styxsksu not ruin.... it would become part of people's strategies... I'd leave a 6 route empty, and then make sure my second to last move leaves me only with one train, to maximise the "free trains" I get from this. It's.... a different meta I guess. (not an enjoyable one imho)

Comment: I can agree with that but it I have also been in the situation where I couldn't complete all of my tickets because the easy route between 2 cities was taken by someone else, so didn't have enough trains to do the other route